# Jackson mixin not being called

Tags: java, json, jackson, mixins

I have already posted something similar but I still trying to zero in on my problem.

Thanks for bearing with me.

It would appear that jackson is not calling a mixin as it should and I can't tell why.

"Element" is an interface not a class.  It is normally instantiated with a static factory call as shown in the mixin (below).  The way I understand it, when jackson sees the interface: Element.class it should look up the mixin then execute the method that has the @JsonCreator annotation.  None of this is happening.  If it were, I would see output from the logger.  Instead, as one can see in the error message (way below), jackson is trying to treat my interface as a class and can't.

Why isn't my mixin working?

Here's the mixin:

```
 public class ElementMixin {

      private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElementMixin.class);

        @JsonCreator
        public static Element create() {
            log.error("Element==>");
            return FhirFactory.eINSTANCE.createElement();
        }
       }
```

Here's how I register it with the mapper:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(Element.class, ElementMixin.class);
```

Here's how I am running things:

```
// Instantiate my interface, put some data in and serialize. 
Element ela = FhirFactory.eINSTANCE.createElement();
ela.setId("CBAEL");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, ela);

// Now try to deserialize into a new instance.
StringReader reader = new StringReader(writer.toString());
Element elp = mapper.readValue(reader, Element.class);//Error thrown
assertNotNull(elp);
```

The error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of fhir.Element, problem: abstract types either need to be
>   mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated
>   with additional type information  at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@4fe533ff; line: 1, column: 1]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:255)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1007)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:150)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3807)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2844)
>     at
>   gov.nist.forecast.fhir.resources.IndexResourceTest.testParametersJSON(IndexResourceTest.java:173)

Answer (score 0):

Mix-ins only associate annotations; they can not and do not add any fields or methods -- no bytecode generation or manipulation is added. So while you can add annotations to indicate methods that already exist in target (including static factory methods) should be used, nothing (aside from annotations) defined in mix-in will ever get called or used.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "associating annotations".

Comment: I don't believe I am adding any fields or methods.  All I want is for jackson to call the appropriate factory method (as opposed to a constructor) every time it sees a registered interface.  I have 646 of these in a 3rd party lib that cannot be altered.  According to this post, it should work [link]http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html[link]

Comment: @GeoffryRoberts so the target class has the matching factory method? If so, that should work. I assumed you expected static method in mix-in class to be called, which would not happen as per my explanation -- mix-in class is not used AT ALL, except for checking annotations it has, "adding" those in with whatever target class has.

Comment: as to "associating annotations": annotations from mix-in class are read, and used by Jackson code as if they existed in target class. But there is no way to add them on the fly without rewriting classes; they are merely associated with the target class. I don't know what you think mix-ins do, but they are really just a way to give Jackson extra annotations to consider. It will not add methods, fields or anything else.